# Nextgen Gallery ImageBrowser Search with Alex's Search Plugin

Tags: wordpress, search, nextgen-gallery

I'm using Nextgen Gallery, latest version, and using a [search plugin](http://alexrabe.de/2010/01/13/search-for-images/). Now here are two problems with searching:

1. Image Order (The search outputs images in ascending order, but I want in descending order)
2. Search is working well when I use simple jQuery effects (Open in Same Window with some lightbox, .. type effects), but when I apply ImageBrowser instead of jquery effect then search returns only images, and on click they returns again the search page, I mean search not opening target images.